# Dorbell Integration Error - The constructor is undefined

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dialog

I want to integrate Doorbell.io into my app, but I get error which I can`t fix it myself.

In eclipse I get this error:

```
The constructor Doorbell(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}, int, String) is undefined
```

This is my code. Anyone can figure out what`s going wrong here?

```
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.rta_dialog_no, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            int appId = myID123; // Replace with your application's ID
            String apiKey = "myAPIkey"; // Replace with your application's API key
            Doorbell doorbellDialog = new Doorbell(this, appId, apiKey); // Create the Doorbell object

            doorbellDialog.setEmail("myemail"); // Prepopulate the email address field
            doorbellDialog.setName("Philip Manavopoulos"); // Set the name of the user (if known)
            doorbellDialog.addProperty("loggedIn", true); // Optionally add some properties
            doorbellDialog.addProperty("username", "whatisthis");
            doorbellDialog.addProperty("loginCount", 123);
            doorbellDialog.setEmailFieldVisibility(View.GONE); // Hide the email field, since we've filled it in already
            doorbellDialog.setPoweredByVisibility(View.GONE); // Hide the "Powered by Doorbell.io" text

            // Callback for when the dialog is shown
            doorbellDialog.setOnShowCallback(new io.doorbell.android.callbacks.OnShowCallback() {
                @Override
                public void handle() {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Dialog shown", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            doorbellDialog.show();


            setOptOut(context, true);
        }
    });
```

RateThisApp.java class

```
package com.kskkbys.rate;

import io.doorbell.android.Doorbell;

import java.util.Date;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class RateThisApp {

private static final String TAG = RateThisApp.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String PREF_NAME = "RateThisApp";
private static final String KEY_INSTALL_DATE = "rta_install_date";
private static final String KEY_LAUNCH_TIMES = "rta_launch_times";
private static final String KEY_OPT_OUT = "rta_opt_out";

private static Date mInstallDate = new Date();
private static int mLaunchTimes = 0;
private static boolean mOptOut = false;

/**
 * Days after installation until showing rate dialog
 */
public static final int INSTALL_DAYS = 0;
/**
 * App launching times until showing rate dialog
 */
public static final int LAUNCH_TIMES = 0;

/**
 * If true, print LogCat
 */
public static final boolean DEBUG = false;

/**
 * Call this API when the launcher activity is launched.<br>
 * It is better to call this API in onStart() of the launcher activity.
 */
public static void onStart(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = pref.edit();
    // If it is the first launch, save the date in shared preference.
    if (pref.getLong(KEY_INSTALL_DATE, 0) == 0L) {
        Date now = new Date();
        editor.putLong(KEY_INSTALL_DATE, now.getTime());
        log("First install: " + now.toString());
    }
    // Increment launch times
    int launchTimes = pref.getInt(KEY_LAUNCH_TIMES, 0);
    launchTimes++;
    editor.putInt(KEY_LAUNCH_TIMES, launchTimes);
    log("Launch times; " + launchTimes);

    editor.commit();

    mInstallDate = new Date(pref.getLong(KEY_INSTALL_DATE, 0));
    mLaunchTimes = pref.getInt(KEY_LAUNCH_TIMES, 0);
    mOptOut = pref.getBoolean(KEY_OPT_OUT, false);

    printStatus(context);
}

/**
 * Show the rate dialog if the criteria is satisfied
 * @param context
 */
public static void showRateDialogIfNeeded(final Context context) {
    if (shouldShowRateDialog()) {
        showRateDialog(context);
    }
}

/**
 * Check whether the rate dialog shoule be shown or not
 * @return
 */
private static boolean shouldShowRateDialog() {
    if (mOptOut) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (mLaunchTimes >= LAUNCH_TIMES) {
            return true;
        }
        long threshold = INSTALL_DAYS * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L;   // msec
        if (new Date().getTime() - mInstallDate.getTime() >= threshold) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Show the rate dialog
 * @param context
 */
public static void showRateDialog(final Context context) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.rta_dialog_title2);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.rta_dialog_message2);

    //If user click button Yes

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.rta_dialog_ok2, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.rta_dialog_title);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.rta_dialog_message);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.rta_dialog_ok, new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String appPackage = context.getPackageName();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackage));
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    setOptOut(context, true);
                }
            });
            builder.setNeutralButton(R.string.rta_dialog_cancel, new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    clearSharedPreferences(context);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.rta_dialog_no, new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    setOptOut(context, true);
                }
            });
            builder.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    clearSharedPreferences(context);
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();


        }


    });

    //If user click NO button

    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.rta_dialog_no2, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

             int appId = 1000; // Replace with your application's ID
                String apiKey = ""; // Replace with your application's API key
                Doorbell doorbellDialog = new Doorbell(this, appId, apiKey); // Create the Doorbell object

                doorbellDialog.setEmail("myemail"); // Prepopulate the email address field
                doorbellDialog.setName("Philip Manavopoulos"); // Set the name of the user (if known)
                doorbellDialog.addProperty("loggedIn", true); // Optionally add some properties
                doorbellDialog.addProperty("username", "whatisthis");
                doorbellDialog.addProperty("loginCount", 123);
                doorbellDialog.setEmailFieldVisibility(View.GONE); // Hide the email field, since we've filled it in already
                doorbellDialog.setPoweredByVisibility(View.GONE); // Hide the "Powered by Doorbell.io" text

                // Callback for when the dialog is shown
                doorbellDialog.setOnShowCallback(new io.doorbell.android.callbacks.OnShowCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle() {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Dialog shown", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

                doorbellDialog.show();

            setOptOut(context, true);
        }
    });
    builder.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            clearSharedPreferences(context);
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
}

/**
 * Clear data in shared preferences.<br>
 * This API is called when the rate dialog is approved or canceled.
 * @param context
 */
private static void clearSharedPreferences(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.remove(KEY_INSTALL_DATE);
    editor.remove(KEY_LAUNCH_TIMES);
    editor.commit();
}

/**
 * Set opt out flag. If it is true, the rate dialog will never shown unless app data is cleared.
 * @param context
 * @param optOut
 */
private static void setOptOut(final Context context, boolean optOut) {
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(KEY_OPT_OUT, optOut);
    editor.commit();
}

/**
 * Print values in SharedPreferences (used for debug)
 * @param context
 */
private static void printStatus(final Context context) {
    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    log("*** RateThisApp Status ***");
    log("Install Date: " + new Date(pref.getLong(KEY_INSTALL_DATE, 0)));
    log("Launch Times: " + pref.getInt(KEY_LAUNCH_TIMES, 0));
    log("Opt out: " + pref.getBoolean(KEY_OPT_OUT, false));
}

/**
 * Print log if enabled
 * @param message
 */
private static void log(String message) {
    if (DEBUG) {
        Log.v(TAG, message);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please include the code of the Doorbell class in your question.

Comment: Here is doorbell class https://github.com/doorbell/android-sdk/tree/master/library/src/io/doorbell/android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Doorbell.io website](https://doorbell.io/docs/android), and gracious assistance from the developer, it seems that the constructor you're using expects an `Activity` as the first argument. In the code you've provided, the `Doorbell` object is instantiated within an anonymous `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` class, so, in that scope, the `this` keyword refers to that anonymous class, which is not an `Activity`. Explicitly reference the current `Activity` by naming the class. For example, if your `Activity` is named `MainActivity`:

```
Doorbell doorbellDialog = new Doorbell(MainActivity.this, appId, apiKey);
```

Comment: I tried this but still got error :(

`Doorbell doorbellDialog = new Doorbell(RateThisApp.this, appId, apiKey);`

`The constructor Doorbell(RateThisApp, int, String) is undefined`

One thing: there is no activity where I want to put this (library RateThisApp for Android)

Comment: excuse me, I m begginer in programming so I don`t undetstand all :) RateThisApp is library with just one class (RateThisApp.java) in src/com.kskkbys.rate... Here is a source code of that class https://github.com/kobakei/Android-RateThisApp/blob/master/library/src/com/kskkbys/rate/RateThisApp.java

Comment: You've not given enough code for me to be certain of what you're doing, but if I'm guessing correctly, change the aforementioned line to: `Doorbell doorbellDialog = new Doorbell(context, appId, apiKey);`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78647/discussion-between-karnak-and-mike-m).

Comment: Thanks again @Mike. I was paste all code in first post. What I want to build is this scenario: When user open app, there is a first dialog with question. If user click Yes, then another dialog was opened, but if user click No I want to show Doorbell email dialog. I hope you understand. Can not figure out how to fix this issue.

Comment: And what happened when you changed the line as I suggested

Comment: Wow, I just modify to this `Doorbell doorbellDialog = new Doorbell((Activity) context, appId, apiKey);`  and now somehow works! Thank you so much @Mike!

Comment: Ah, very good! From the info I'd read on that page, I assumed a Context was acceptable, as Doorbell's an AlertDialog subclass, but it apparently needs specifically an Activity. Nice work!

Comment: Hey guys! I'm the guy who made Doorbell. 

The reason why I had overridden the constructor was to gather more info about the activity on which the Dialog is opened. https://github.com/doorbell/android-sdk/blob/master/library/src/io/doorbell/android/Doorbell.java#L153

Sorry this caused confusion! :)

Comment: @manavo Hey! No worries. It's my fault for having made assumptions based on just the first web page I found. I should've investigated further. Thanks for the info! I'll correct my answer when I get to a desktop later. Cheers!

Comment: Your answer is correct @MikeM, you reference the activity there. But might be worth putting a little note there that it requires an activity and not just a context! :)

Thanks for helping Karnak through it!